# Screen flickering then driver crashing when using dual monitors on laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, laptop-display

I've had an ASUS N55SL-DS71 for a few years now. It has an i7-2670QM with Intel Graphics 3000 and an Nvidia GT 635M 2G. I generally use it with two external monitors attached and the laptop screen off.

This problem started on Windows 7 and has persisted on Windows 10.

Recently, I've been having an issue where, when both monitors are plugged in, the screen will start flickering and tearing on the second monitor. It will gradually get worse until it finally goes black and Windows reports that the display driver has crashed but recovered.

The issue is the same if I use the laptop screen with a single extra monitor. I've tried all combinations of laptop screen/VGA connected monitor/HDMI connected monitor. I've tried switching cables and monitors. Whichever display is set as the secondary one always eventually fails. It just can't seem to handle two monitors anymore.

It has no problem playing 3D games using the Nvidia processor, as long as only one monitor is in use. The problem seems to be with the Intel graphics.

It only seems to have issues while on a single monitor when I'm outside of Windows. i.e. during the upgrade to Windows 10, I had no external monitors attached, and the laptop screen flickered like crazy. I'm also pretty sure I've seen it flicker during POST, but I can't remember for sure.

So far, I've tried reinstalling the Intel graphics adapter driver and the Nvidia driver. When that didn't work, I did a fresh install of Windows. I've also tried upgrading from Windows 7 to 10, then did a clean install of Windows 10. Since none of these things have helped, and since the problem gradually gets worse over the course of minutes (or sometimes hours if I'm lucky) until the display finally shuts off, I'm pretty sure it's a hardware issue.

- Is there any chance that I missed something and this is still a software issue?
- Is it possible to force the laptop to rely solely on the Nvidia card?
- If it's definitely hardware, what is the most likely culprit? My first instinct is the graphics portion of the CPU, but could it be the memory or something else more easily replaceable?
- If it is the CPU, is it possible for me to replace that, or is it soldered onto the board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this laptop working again. I've been using it for about two months now without a single screen flickering issue, so I'm confident that the problems I was seeing are resolved.

Unfortunately, I can't say exactly what the problem was or what fixed it, other than that it was a hardware problem.

I fixed it by taking the laptop apart completely. I removed the heat sinks/heat pipes from the CPU and GPU. I cleaned off all of the old thermal paste from everything. It turns out the video card isn't integrated directly into the motherboard but is a separate small card plugged into a port, sitting in a cutout section of the main board. So I took that out, cleaned the connection and re-seated it. Then I applied new thermal paste and put everything back together.

After re-assembling the laptop, everything works great. It's possible that something was loose and re-assembling it fixed that problem. It might have been an overheating issue that was fixed by re-seating the heat pipes. The factory thermal paste was spread everywhere, so cleaning that up might have helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking a wild guess, but Windows 10 has ITB (in the box) driver for Nvidia. You could try over installing previous whql driver for your system. Provided that the monitor you are running is driven through Nvidia GPU. To check that, Open Nvidia control panel, goto set physX page, you'll see the ports driven by each GPU.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
Wait for the updated Intel display driver for your computer.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/

For your model:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81502/Intel-HD-Graphics-2000-for-2nd-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors

(The link is correct despite saying Intel HD Graphics 2000)
It only shows drivers for Windows 8.1. You can try it, but it may not work.

I have a dual-monitor setup with my laptop (ASUS X450JF, Intel i7-4700HQ with Intel HD Graphics 4600) and upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10. My laptop screen flickered all the time, even with the cable unplugged. In the end, the problem lies in the Intel display driver. Updating to the new Intel display driver for Windows 10 solved the problem. Reinstalling the latest NVIDIA driver doesn't help, since the desktop or in general Windows is rendered with the Intel HD Graphics.

My driver came out just 2 days ago (19-9-2015), so I believe the solution is to wait some days for Intel to roll out their drivers.